# Combine two JSON objects javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have two different JSON objects, one

```
[{"pmid":"29092960","MemberID":"33"},{"pmid":"28652336","MemberID":"33"}]
```

and the other like

```
{
    "meta": {
        "refs": 0, 
        "pmids": "29092960,28652336"
    }, 
    "links": {
        "self": "https://icite.od.nih.gov/api/pubs?refs=0&pmids=23456789%2C27599104"
    }, 
    "data": [
        {
            "pmid": 29092960, 
            "doi": "10.1002/cncr.27976", 
            "authors": "ABC, XYZ", 
            "journal": "Cancer", 
            "year": 2013
        }, 
        {
            "pmid": 28652336, 
            "doi": "10.1371/journal.pbio.1002541", 
            "authors": "Bbbb", 
            "journal": "PLoS Biol.", 
            "year": 2016
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to combine these?  The first object I create by loop a grid and adding items. The second one comes from an api that I need to add additional data.  This does not look like the structure of any other example that I have found. I would like to link based upon the pmid value as a key

I would like the output to be

```
       {"pmid": 29092960, 
        "doi": "10.1002/cncr.27976", 
        "authors": "ABC, XYZ", 
        "journal": "Cancer", 
        "year": 2013,
         "MemberID":"33"},{
         "pmid": 29092960, 
        "doi": "10.1002/cncr.27976", 
        "authors": "ABC, XYZ", 
        "journal": "Cancer", 
        "year": 2013,
       "MemberID": "33"}
```

Comment: Can you be more precise on what your expected output is?

Comment: what object **structure** are you wanting to end up with?  The **first** or the **second**?  or a 3rd?, are you wanting to **add** the **MemberID** from the **first** into the **second** ?.  You question is rather vague.  **Combining** could mean many things.

Comment: inside loop `Object.assign(obj1,obj2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine two JSON objects javaScript

```js
let arr1 =[{"pmid":"29092960","MemberID":"33"},{"pmid":"28652336","MemberID":"33"}];


let arr2 = {
    "meta": {
        "refs": 0, 
        "pmids": "29092960,28652336"
    }, 
    "links": {
        "self": "https://icite.od.nih.gov/api/pubs?refs=0&pmids=23456789%2C27599104"
    }, 
    "data": [
        {
            "pmid": 29092960, 
            "doi": "10.1002/cncr.27976", 
            "authors": "ABC, XYZ", 
            "journal": "Cancer", 
            "year": 2013
        }, 
        {
            "pmid": 28652336, 
            "doi": "10.1371/journal.pbio.1002541", 
            "authors": "Bbbb", 
            "journal": "PLoS Biol.", 
            "year": 2016
        }
    ]
};

let arr3 = [];

arr1.forEach((itm, i) => {
  arr3.push(Object.assign({}, itm, arr2.data.find(k => k.pmid==itm.pmid)));
});
console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'll work on this tonight with both yours and Spangle's solutions.  I can see that they both solve my problem

Comment: @user1314159 Can you please mark this answer correct if answered is useful!!

Answer (score 1):

You sure can combine objects.

For in loops will help you get the job done and are a good thing to keep in your back pocket when working with objects.

I have provided a solution below.

```js
var obj1 = [{"pmid":"29092960","MemberID":"33"},{"pmid":"28652336","MemberID":"33"}];

var obj2 = {
    "meta": {
        "refs": 0, 
        "pmids": "29092960,28652336"
    }, 
    "links": {
        "self": "https://icite.od.nih.gov/api/pubs?refs=0&pmids=23456789%2C27599104"
    }, 
    "data": [
        {
            "pmid": 29092960, 
            "doi": "10.1002/cncr.27976", 
            "authors": "ABC, XYZ", 
            "journal": "Cancer", 
            "year": 2013
        }, 
        {
            "pmid": 28652336, 
            "doi": "10.1371/journal.pbio.1002541", 
            "authors": "Bbbb", 
            "journal": "PLoS Biol.", 
            "year": 2016
        }
    ]
};


for(var char in obj1){
 for(var innerArr in obj2.data){
       // obj2 pmid is a number, so convert it to a string for the compare
  if(obj1[char].pmid === obj2.data[char].pmid.toString()){
   obj2.data[char].MemberID = obj1[char].MemberID;
  }
 }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj2.data));
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'll work on this tonight with both your and Mohammad solutions.  I can see that they both solve my problem

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have any further questions

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution to this can be achieved using **[Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** in conjunction with **[Object.Assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)**:

```js
let arr = [
  {"pmid":"29092960","MemberID":"33"},
  {"pmid":"28652336","MemberID":"33"}
];

let json = {
  "meta": {
    "refs": 0, 
    "pmids": "29092960,28652336"
  }, 
  "links": {
    "self": "https://icite.od.nih.gov/api/pubs?refs=0&pmids=23456789%2C27599104"
  }, 
  "data": [
    {
      "pmid": 29092960, 
      "doi": "10.1002/cncr.27976", 
      "authors": "ABC, XYZ", 
      "journal": "Cancer", 
      "year": 2013
    }, 
    {
      "pmid": 28652336, 
      "doi": "10.1371/journal.pbio.1002541", 
      "authors": "Bbbb", 
      "journal": "PLoS Biol.", 
      "year": 2016
    }
  ]
};

let res = arr.map(({pmid, MemberID}) =>
{
    return Object.assign({pmid, MemberID}, json.data.find(o => o.pmid === +pmid));
});

console.log(res);
```

Note, the **[unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())** is used to coerces (or cast) the `pmid` of the original array to a number. From the reference you can read:

> Unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number

However, and like on other answers, you can use `o.pmid == pmid` in replacement of `o.pmid === +pmid`.